# Firebase REST API not parsing JSON when using VBA in Excel

Tags: json, excel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble sending JSON data to a firebase database using the rest API, the data is sent, but it does not parse.  For instance if I use this curl command in command prompt in windows:

```
curl -X PUT -d  "{\"lastName\":\"Jones\",\"firstName\":\"Bubba\"}"   https://<database-name>.firebaseio.com/rest/test/.json
```

That results in the correct parsing of the data:
[image: Correct Parsing of JSON data]

Yet, when using the following VBA code:

```
Sub PUSHhttpRequestTest()  'Doesn't Work!!

    Dim sc As Object
    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    Dim strURL As String: strURL = "https://<database-name>.firebaseio.com/rest/.json"

    Dim strRequest
    strRequest = """{\""lastName\"":\""Jones\"",\""firstName\"":\""Bubba\""}"""
    Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    Dim response As String
    Debug.Print strRequest
    XMLhttp.Open "PUT", strURL, False
    XMLhttp.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    XMLhttp.sEnd strRequest
    response = XMLhttp.responseText
    Debug.Print response
End Sub
```

This sends exactly the same stringified JSON, and it gets added to the Firebase database, however, the JSON string doesn't get parsed:
[image]

I have tried different Content Types, and variations on the JSON string, but nothing seems to work.  Can anyone explain how I can get the VBA script to send data that Firebase will parse?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution to sending JSON data from excel to firebase, but it doesn't answer my question about why the above VBA code sending a Stringified JSON doesn't get parsed in Firebase.   I would still like a solution to that, because I already have a function the creates the stringified JSON from my data.

Using the [VBA-web Library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021540/post-json-to-web-in-excel-vba) seems to do the trick.  The example uses dictionaries for your data, however please [my comment and the subsequent reply](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/361#issuecomment-412880991) regarding the format of the JSON string to send.  **No escape code is required!**

There is no PUT, and Other request types for json, but you can easily add these in yourself.

The equivalent code to the above, but using VBA-web library (with custom PutJson function) is:

```
Sub test()

Dim strURL As String: strURL = "https://<database-name>/rest/test/whatwhat/.json"
Dim strRequest As String: strRequest = "{""LastName"":""Jones"",""firstName"":""Bubba""}"

Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Response As WebResponse
Set Response = Client.PutJson(strURL, strRequest)

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Response.Content
End Sub
```

And we end up with this....

[image: correct parsing]

Happy Days!

However, I'd still like to know why the seemingly identical curl and VBA HTTP requests result in different parsing of the data in FireBase?