# Translate "-d" in VBA when doing an HTTP Request

Tags: vba, filter, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I try to get a list of actions from iAuditor filtered by "template_id" by sending an HTTP Request with VBA. For the moment I have this code that return the list of all actions:

```
Sub Get_Data()
Dim hReq As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim authKey As String
Dim response As String

authKey = "d8a0df7d7e1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXff3c765cf2fcf"

Set sht = Sheets(1)

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://api.safetyculture.io/tasks/v1/actions/list"
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send
    End With


    response = hReq.ResponseText
    'MsgBox Len(response)
    sht.Range("A1") = response
End Sub
```

Now I want to "translate" a filter to VBA but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my API Documentation about the website : https://developer.safetyculture.io/#actions

So what i want to translate in VBA looks like this in HTTP code i guess :

```
curl -X POST "https://api.safetyculture.io/tasks/v1/actions/list" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {api_token}" \
-d {
  "template_id": {
    "operator": 7,
    "value": ["fc2e53f6-4712-4ca5-b681-aba3ac954217"]
  }
}
```

I thank You a lot for any help you can offer me.

Regards,
Gabin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did it !!! :D

Here is my final code:

```
Sub Get_Data()
Dim hReq As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim authKey As String
Dim response As String
Dim response_objet As Object
Dim Body As String

authKey = "d8a0df7d7e19XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc65ec9eff3c765cf2fcf"

Body = "{ ""filters"": [ { ""template_id"": { ""value"": [""884b95df35104f4792a3c1fdfed63f0e""]}}]}"
Set sht = Sheets(1)
sht.Range("A3") = Body
Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "https://api.safetyculture.io/tasks/v1/actions/list"
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send Body
    End With


    response = hReq.ResponseText
    'MsgBox Len(response)
    sht.Range("A1") = response
    Set response_objet = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    For Each Item In response_objet
        a = a + 1
        Sheets("Biblio").Range("B" & a) = Item
    Next Item
End Sub
```

Huge thanks to @CodingWolf , he put me on the right direction.

Have a nice day internet.
Gabin,

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread:
https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?592624-Posting-data-using-XMLHttpRequest

you can add Data to a POST Request by passing it as a value in the send function:

```
hReq.send "'template_id': {'operator': 7,'value': ['fc2e53f6-4712-4ca5-b681-aba3ac954217']}"
```

Values are differentiated by a & Symbol inside the string.

Comment: I've try differents commands nothing is working: .Send ("template_id&operator=7&value=3379ae0a-5951-414c-be34-8aaf35836bf7") and the result error message is: "invalid character 'e' in literal true (expecting 'r')",

Comment: @Legomanfr Right, I must apologize, I had VB and VBA confused. Please try   

.Send "template_id&operator=7&value=3379ae0a-5951-414c-be34-8aaf35836bf7"

without the parenthesis

Comment: Same error message: "invalid character 'e' in literal true (expecting 'r')", I have try an easier exemple like this one: -d '{
      "page_size": 10
    }' tranlated to : .Send "page_size=10" and it's not working aswell

Comment: @Legomanfr Sorry, I was not able to reproduce your specific error message. But I have noticed that in most other examples, the Object is named MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP. Yours is named MSXML2.XMLHTTP, without the Server prefix. Can you please change that and see if it does anything?

Comment: Re, on my professional computer I have this error: Run-time error '-2147012739 (80072f7d)': An error occurred in the secure channel support     I think it's due to my IT Security.. I've try on my personnal computer, no run-time error but the same response: "invalid character 'e' in literal true (expecting 'r')"

Comment: For clarification, do you get the error message from VBA, or from the API response?

Comment: From API response. exept for Run-time error '-2147012739 (80072f7d)': An error occurred in the secure channel support that came from VBA. The exact response I have from API is this message: {
  "code":  3,
  "message":  "invalid character 'e' in literal true (expecting 'r')",
  "details":  []
}

Comment: I have try this command: .Send "{""template_id"":{""operator"":7,""value"":[""3379ae0a-5951-414c-be34-8aaf35836bf7""]}" and I have a diffferent error from response API this is maybe a clue: {
  "code":  3,
  "message":  "unexpected EOF",
  "details":  []
}

Comment: Ah, yes, this clears things up. I have edited my response accordingly, replacing the double quotes with single quotes so it works.

Comment: Here the response with your edited message: {
  "code":  3,
  "message":  "invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value",
  "details":  []
}                       I feel we  are getting closer and closer to the right command =)

Comment: Love the details of the response, that really helps :P Did you use hReq.send "'template_id': or hReq.send "{'template_id':? Maybe try adding a set of brackets at the beginning and end

Comment: With or Withou bracketsthe response is the same. I have try to change the  quotation marks like this .Send "{""template_id"": {""operator"": 7,""value"": [""fc2e53f6-4712-4ca5-b681-aba3ac954217""]}}"                and the response is different maybe it can help:           {
  "code":  3,
  "message":  "proto: (line 1:2): unknown field \"template_id\"",
  "details":  []
}

Comment: Can you perhaps try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22963279/9118389) suggestions to see if the JSON is correct? Because I am running out of ideas to be honest.

Comment: I've tested with a variable that hold the JSON text, also JSON is correct according to JSON Validator... same API response error :-( Thanks for help dude you make me progress anyway