# How to use SQL to input an Invoice to Xero

Tags: sql, xero-api

I have an MSaccess frontend connected to CDATA odbc connector to Xero accounting. All connected and usable but I am struggling how to insert a multi line invoice using SQL. Xero developer keeps referring to using their API using puts\gets but nothing about using SQL. Can do a single line invoice but not multiline as it assign a new GUID to every line

Has anybody had experience on using SQL directly into XERO for invoices.

Tried using SQL INSERT which works but it's the connecting the individual lines in a single invoice that I can;t get?

Comment: If you don't use the API provided by Xero, and instead use SQL, there is no guarantee (by Xero) that what you create is valid. For example, Xero may release a new version where and extra table needs to be populated. Their API will automatically support this, but your manual SQL insert will not. First consider whether you want to use an unsupported method to maintain your financial data. You wouldn't want to create an invoice using this method and accidentally invoice the wrong amount or the wrong customer, or not have that invoice appear

Comment: Thanks Nick, appreciate your comments and I agree. Only problem is that the API seems to be using PUTS\GETS using webhooks and I am using VBA in MSACCESS so I am struggling to understand how this can work ? I just need a breadcrumb to understand it :-)

Comment: You just need a VBA library that works with web API's. Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246789/how-do-we-use-restful-apis-from-excel-macros-vba You are effectively calling a function with parameters just like any other, however you happen to be shooting that function call over HTTP.

Comment: Note that GET is like select, PUT is like UPDATE and POST is like insert/update. Looking at the web API, you need to create JSON out of  your parameter values and put it in the body, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021540/post-json-to-web-in-excel-vba

Comment: The biggest challenge is usually authentication, becaase you first need to call a web service to get a token, and use that token in all subsequent web api calls

Comment: Forgive me, I did a bit of internet sleuthing, I wish I had helped with this question 18 months ago when I started my Wilston Qlder renovation!!!!!

Comment: As an update - after much person development with the XERO API, its the way to go. I just wish the API manual\examples were more explicit as there is alot of hit and miss to get VBA code to work. Happy to share if anybody is interested